# Track DE in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I want to track multiple journey campaigns,
So I decided to create a DE to track subscriber logs.
My question is :
Is it better to create a DE for each journey? Or to track all logs within a DE?   However, the "Update contact Activity", will overwrite the previous data and risk losing the previous logs. 
Which can be the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally opt for a single log data extension as outlined in [**the solution here**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/journey-logging-using-update-contact/).  If there's a possibility that a subscriber can be in more than one journey *at the same time* and have activity *within the same hour*, then you should use multiple log data extensions.  I'd argue that's generally unlikely.

[image: Journey_Builder_Status]

[image: Journey_Builder_Log]

The whole point of having *Journey* as a field in the status and logging data extensions is to use it with multiple journeys.

Comment: sorry for this question. but if I do the query with the update activity * if a subscriber is in two different journeys the query will add the record or overwrite it? For example in Journey_builder_log i Will have; subscriberkey: 1293 journey: welcome Subscriberkey:1293 journey: promotion

Comment: If you follow my solution, if those events happen within the same hour in two separate journeys, yes (even though both queries are upserts).  But how likely is that in your scenario?

Comment: if they occur at different times do not overwrite? no I have no scenarios. I have to implement this solution and I would like to be sure

Comment: I'd suggest testing it if you have concerns. Once the row has been swept to the log it's protected by the primary key that includes a timestamp.

Comment: it is for this reason that you have put two primarykeys in DE log?                                    
sorry but I didn't know about the timestamp was inclusd of primary Key, I'm new to the platform SFMC.

Comment: @MaryjON I’ve noticed you never accept any answers to your questions on this site - please make sure to do that as people are putting a lot of effort into helping you out and the least you can do is mark the most helpful answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank u zuzannamj I didn't know with validating the answer. But I recently signed up, and at first she didn't let me validate it.